why is typescript subclass returning superclass?
import * as pl from "nodejs-polars"

const foo: pl.Datetime = pl.Datetime("ms")

is getting Property 'timeUnit' is missing in type 'DataType' but required in type 'Datetime'. error. when hovered, pl.Datetime("ms") actually returns pl.DataType the superclass, not pl.Datetime which is confusing.
Playground Link

Why is that confusing, why did you expect something else, what is wrong about that behaviour (other than your expectation)? It matches the docs https://pola-rs.github.io/nodejs-polars/functions/Datetime.html .

The pl.Datatime() function returns a DataType, not a DateTime object, see here.
If you change your foo type to DataType, it's working fine.

@Nicolas It returns a Datetime instance that is a DataType instance. OP is asking why the static methods are not typed more precisely.
